# javascript, texto que siempre se repita, alguna solución?

Tags: javascript, condiciones, setinterval, texto

llevo 2 días calentándome la cabeza con este código, quiero que se repita siempre que palabra.length === 0, o eso es lo que creo.

Es un efecto maquina de escribir que escribe el texto, después de escribirlo hace una pausa de unos segundos, *lo hice con `setTimeout`* y después de esos segundos lo borre.

El problema que tengo es que no se como hacer para que una vez termine todo eso vuelva a iniciar de nuevo, he probado muchas formas, he hecho que se escriba y se borre automáticamente con `setInterval` pero si quiero que se repita el ciclo ya me es imposible...

Adjunto el código con el que he intentado, pero me falta que se repita.

Si alguno tiene una solución sería de agradecer.

```js
const texto = document.querySelector('.textoAnimado')
const palabra = texto.innerHTML
const escribir = 'Galeria'
let i = 0
let j = escribir.length

function animacion1() {
  setInterval(escribirTexto(), 1500)
}

function escribirTexto() {
  setInterval(() => {
    if (i < escribir.length) {
      texto.innerHTML += escribir[i];
      i++;
    }
  }, 150);
}
let animacion2 = setInterval(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (i == escribir.length) {
      texto.innerHTML = escribir.substring(-1, j);
      j--;
    }
  }, 3000);
}, 150);
if (palabra.length === 0) {
  animacion1()
}
```

```html
<H3 class="textoAnimado"></H3>
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Danos un poco más de contexto por favor, vendría bien una parte del código `HTML` para reproducir el problema.

Comment: Hola, cuando decis "escriba", te referís a "letra por letra" o toda la palabra?, de donde saldría **palabra.length === 0**, iniciar de nuevo, implica volver a escribir la palabra que borrro?.

Comment: hola, agregué el html pero lo borré despues, no tiene nada de importante es una estiqueta h3 con la clase .textoAnimado
es el primer codigo que adjunto y no quería hacerme un lio al adjuntarlo

Comment: hola marce, si, me refiero a letra por letra, es una animación tipo maquina de escribir que escribe luego espera unos segundos y despues lo borra para volver a escribirlo. palabra.length === 0 es para vover a mandar a llamar la funcion animacion1 que es que empieze a escribir,

Comment: modificando el codigo anteriormente coun un set interval y if y else hice la animacion de escribir y borrar automáticamente, pero a la hora de meter un settimeout para que pausara al terminar de escribir y empezar a borrar da fallos la animacion, supongo que por los tiempos de interval y timeout que cada uno van a su bola... 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con dos funciones es suficiente, la de escribir y la de eliminar el texto.

El código está comentado, si tienes dudas deja un comentario.

```js
const texto = document.querySelector('.textoAnimado')
const palabra = texto.innerHTML
const escribir = 'Galeria'
let i = 0
let j = escribir.length

//Ejecutar la función al cargar la pagina
escribirTexto()

function escribirTexto() {
  //Asignar el set interval a una variable
  let iniciarEscritura = setInterval(() => {
    if (i < escribir.length) {
      texto.innerHTML += escribir[i];
      i++;
    } else {
      //Limpiar el set interval...
      clearInterval(iniciarEscritura);
      //Reiniciar i
      i = 0
      setTimeout(() => {
        //Ejecutar la función para eliminar el texto
        eliminarTexto();
      }, 2000);
    }
  }, 150);
}

function eliminarTexto() {
  //Asignar el set interval a una variable
  let iniciarBorrado = setInterval(() => {
    if (j != 0) {
      texto.innerHTML = escribir.substring(-1, j - 1);
      j--;
    } else {
      //Limpiar el set interval...
      clearInterval(iniciarBorrado);
      //Reiniciar j
      j = escribir.length
      setTimeout(() => {
        //Ejecutar la función para escribir el texto
        escribirTexto();
      }, 2000);
    }
  }, 150);
}
```

```html
<H3 class="textoAnimado"></H3>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, llevo poco tiempo aprendiendo JavaScript , vaya 2 dias perdidos con esto llevo...

Comment: No lo consideres tiempo perdido, todo aprendizaje toma tiempo. Si mi respuesta fue de utilidad para tu solucionar tu caso, te invito a aceptarla con el check que está al lado izquierdo, debajo de los botones para votar.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, ya he podido terminar el código. Quedó muy chulo. Adjunto resultado abajo

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a la ayuda que he recibido he conseguido terminar el código, al final ha quedado muy bien. Adjunto resultado.
La barra de escritura al terminar de escribir parpadea con el CSS que he añadido, aunque aquí no se muestra desconozco el motivo.

```js
const texto = document.querySelector('.textoAnimado')
const palabra = texto.innerHTML
let escribir = [' Front-end Developer', ' Técnico Informático', ' Técnico industrial']
let i = 0
let contador = 0
let seleccionar = escribir[contador].length
let barraAnimacion = document.getElementById('barra')

//Ejecuta la funcion al cargar la pagina
escribirTexto()

function escribirTexto (){
    //asignar al set interval una variable
    let iniciarEscritura =  setInterval(() => {
        if( i < escribir[contador].length) {
            texto.innerHTML += escribir[contador][i];
            i++;
        } else {
            // Parpadeo barra escribir al terminar el texto
            barraAnimacion.classList.add('barra-escribir')
            //Limpiar el set interval
            clearInterval(iniciarEscritura)
            //Reiniciar i
            i=0
            //reiniciar seleccionar, para que el largo de la palabra empiece de nuevo
            seleccionar = escribir[contador].length
            setTimeout(() => {
                //Ejecutar la funcion para eliminar el texto
                borrarTexto()
                //Reiniciar parpadeo
                barraAnimacion.classList.remove('barra-escribir')
            }, 3000);
        }
    }, 100);
}
function borrarTexto(){
    //Asignar al setInterval una variable
    let iniciarBorrado = setInterval(() => {
        if( seleccionar != -1){
            texto.innerHTML = escribir[contador].substring(-1, seleccionar - 1);
            seleccionar--;
        } else {
            //Limpiar el setInterval
            clearInterval(iniciarBorrado)
            //reiniciar seleccionar, para que el largo de la palabra empiece de nuevo
            seleccionar = escribir[contador].length
            // contardor siguiente string del arreglo
            contador++
            // si el contador a terminado todas las posiciones del string, reiniciarlo para volver a empezar
            if (contador == escribir.length){
                contador = 0
            }
            setTimeout(() => {
                //Ejecutar la funcion para volver a escribir el texto
                escribirTexto()
            }, 50);
        }
    }, 150);
}
```

```css
.barra-escribir {
    animation: 0.7s parpadeo infinite;
};

@keyframes parpadeo {
    50%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<h3>Soy<span class="textoAnimado"></span><span id="barra">|</span></h3>
```